# UnInstall Docker but still get request

Tags: docker, wireshark

I recently install docker, but just uninstall it after a couple of test.

I am very surprise to see that "network request" continue to be send to "host.docker.internal" when i run WireShark.

Any idea ?

[image]

Comment: You do realize that’s _your_ host name...?

Comment: @DanielB no i don't, i just take a look in my Host file and you are right. That point to my internal ip address. Thanks